# JSONPath на Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, xpath, json.net

```
{ "name" : "root", "childrens":[{"name":"TestDiscipline1","childrens":
    [{"name":"NewFolderInSpeciality","childrens":
        [{"name":"FirstMaterialWithModel", "packadgeURL":"testPath", "modelName":"FirstModel"},
        {"name":"SecondMaterialWithModel", "packadgeURL":"testPath", "modelName":"SecondModel"},
        {"name":"ThirdMaterialWithModel", "packadgeURL":"testPath", "modelName":"ThirdModel"}]
    }]
}]}
```

Какие есть библиотеки для работы с `JSON` для `Unity`, которые позволят формировать запрос динамически (что-то вроде `xpath`) и выбирать по нему элементы из подобного `JSON`? Может есть какой-то другой вариант выборки элементов?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) встроенную в Unity.